# FBA in hosted SharePoint 

Tags: forms-authentication, login, database

Does anyone have details on how to create Forms based Authentication using SharePoint 2010?
I have a scenario where i want users to login and view information relating to them from a database.

This ideally would mean that that their userid would serve as an input parameter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Steve Peschka had an excellent [series of articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on FBA for SharePoint 2007 but I don't think they were updated for 2010. So perhaps a better choice would be [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/12/31/configuring-forms-based-authentication-for-claims-based-web-applications.aspx) by Russ Maxwell, this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890.aspx) or this [blog entry on TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

Otherwise I suggest the [following link](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22forms%20based%20authentication%22%20sharepoint%202010) ;-)

Comment: +1 "Following link" :)